# Increment a cell value every 23rd line

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have the statement below at every 23rd line in an excel sheet CSV format (there are no formulae in the document, I just assumed using excel would be the easiest way to change this!)

`wp_pos=(13.0479,0.100,-165.4428)` - the values are always different

I want to change every occurence of the 2nd value, (in this instance 0.100)

I want to change it to a total value of 'cell value + 0.200 (i.e. 0.30)

If the document is put into excel then line

Cell A is `wp_pos=(13.0479,0.100)`

Cell B is 0.100 <-- it's this value I wish to change

How do I do it for every 23rd line?

Comment: A macro/VBA would be the way to do it. If you don't know how perhaps someone will help you with the code.

Answer (score 3):

If cell A contains `wp_pos=(13.0479,0.100,-165.4428)` then the first step is to split the values out.  So select column A and go to `Data/Text to Columns`.  Choose comma the delimeters.

Now you will have

```
A = wp_pos=(13.0479
B = 0.100
C = -165.4428)
```

In column D1, put

```
=if(mod(row(),23)=0,B1+.2,B1)
```

This will check if the row number is divisible by 23 exactly, and if so, D1 will contain B1 + .2, otherwise it will contain B1

In E1 put

```
=concatenate(A1,",",D1,",",C1)
```

This will join everything back together again.  Copy D1 and E1 down for the length of your data

You can now copy column E1 and paste special (values) into a new sheet, so you just get formulas, then export.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll give it a try :)......It didn't quite work I must have done something wrong! But I found a workaround using your idea. Many Thanks :)

Comment: @Tonto The "23rd" value in the description may be the issue - is this an hour figure?  If so, there are 24 hours in a day, so it would need pick the right row in each 24 hour period, not each 23rd value.

Comment: I don't think I explain myself too well. No it isn't an hr value.the 'wp_pos' line appears every 23rd line down eg B1, B24,B47 etc. I said ROW but meant Column, sorry. However I changed your formula to 'column', but it didn't make any difference. I couldn't paste your formula all the way down the page or it would have affected the other values in B2-B23, which I didn't want. I used in D1 =SUM(B1+0.2) and then your E1 formula which worked fine, but I would have to paste it into over 700 separate lines to achieve my goal. Never mind!Thanks for your help. I'll try the adjustment using Basic!

Answer (score 0):

My proposal below assumes `wp_pos=(13.0479,0.1,-165.4428)` in column A will be replaced with `wp_pos=(13.0479,0.3,-165.4428)` in the same column (wherever "wp_pos" occurs in this column) but having re-read the question and comments this may not be the requirement. In which case.. ignore me!

I have a slightly complicated formula - don't know if it is of interest:

```
=REPLACE(A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1,SEARCH(",",A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A4,1)-1,TEXT(VALUE(MID(A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1,SEARCH(",",A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1)-'SEARCH(",",A4,1)-1)+0.2),"@"))
```

**Added**: Slightly simplified version:

```
=REPLACE(A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1,SEARCH(",",A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A4,1)-1,MID(A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1,SEARCH(",",A4,SEARCH(",",A4,1)+1)-SEARCH(",",A4,1)-1)+0.2)
```

I assume it could, possibly, be simplified further.

I would approach inserting these formulas in a slightly different way, but I'm assuming that `wp_pos=` is a criteria we can use? Rather than every 23rd row. If not, then ignore me again!

Anyway, in case it is of interest, but I apologise that it is a bit *elaborate*:

- It the data doesn't already have column headings, create a dummy heading row. Just insert it at the top, type Heading1 and drag this to the right. Drag one column further than the last occupied column.
- Use **AutoFilter** and for the first column, choose `Custom Filter` and 'begins with', type 'wp_pos`.
- Click the first data-cell (of the first column) and press `Ctrl-Shift-Down` to highlight to the bottom.
- Press `Ctrl-Shift-Right` to extend the selection to the end.
- `Shift-Right` to include the blank column.
- Press `Ctrl . (period)` to make the cell at the top-right corner the active cell.
- `Ctrl-Shift-Right` to collapse the selection to just this column. You may have to press this a couple of times, until only this blank column is selected.
- Type the formula into the active cell, changing A4 to whichever is the current row number.
- Press `Ctrl-Enter` to fill this formula into the selected cells.

You can't `Copy/Paste-Special, Values` with the current selection. So you need to remove the filter, select this new column, then Copy/Paste-Special, Values (over the same column). Then copy the same column again, select the first column. Right-click to find Paste-Special and click the option to **skip blanks**. The original wp_pos cells will be replaced, but the others will remain intact.

As I said, elaborate! But this outline may contain some useful information (for someone..).